How to use a custom behaviour in MAUI
In my .NET 8 MAUI project, I have a custom component that returns my model. For this, component, I created a custom behaviour - this is the code:
public class IsLanguageNullOrEmptyBehavior : Behavior<LanguageDropdown>
{
    static readonly BindablePropertyKey IsEmptyPropertyKey = 
        BindableProperty.CreateReadOnly("IsEmpty", typeof(bool), 
            typeof(IsLanguageNullOrEmptyBehavior), false);

    public static readonly BindableProperty IsEmptyProperty = 
        IsEmptyPropertyKey.BindableProperty;

    public bool IsEmpty
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsEmptyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsEmptyProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(LanguageDropdown bindable)
    {
        base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
        bindable.SelectedItemChanged += Bindable_SelectedItemChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(LanguageDropdown bindable)
    {
        base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
        bindable.SelectedItemChanged -= Bindable_SelectedItemChanged;
    }

    private void Bindable_SelectedItemChanged(object? sender, LanguageModel e)
    {
        if (e is null)
            IsEmpty = true;
        else
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.LanguageName) || 
                string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Abbreviation))
                IsEmpty = true;
            else
                IsEmpty = false;
        }
    }
}

Now, in a ContentView, I want to use this behaviour to change the color of the border of the controller. For that, I want to check if the LanguageTarget has a value.
So, I wrote this code:
<ContentPage
    xmlns:bhl="clr-namespace:LanguageDropdown.Behavious;assembly=LanguageDropdown"
    xmlns:ldd="clr-namespace:LanguageDropdown;assembly=LanguageDropdown">

    <ldd:LanguageDropdown
        SelectedItem="{Binding LanguageTarget}">
        <ldd:LanguageDropdown.Behaviors>
            <bhl:IsLanguageNullOrEmptyBehavior
                x:Name="emptyLanguageItem" />
        </ldd:LanguageDropdown.Behaviors>
        <ldd:LanguageDropdown.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger TargetType="ldd:LanguageDropdown">
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <BindingCondition 
                        Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference emptyLanguageItem}, 
                            Path=IsEmpty}" 
                        Value="True" />
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="BorderColor" 
                        Value="{StaticResource PlaceholderAlert}" />
            </MultiTrigger>
        </ldd:LanguageDropdown.Triggers>
    </ldd:LanguageDropdown>

The issue is that when the property IsEmpty changed, the color of the border doesn't change.
Update
I tried to add this DataTrigger
<ldd:LanguageDropdown
    x:Name="lddTarget"
    SelectedItem="{Binding LanguageTarget}"
    SemanticProperties.Description="{lang:Translate DictionaryLanguage}"
    TextSize="{StaticResource ElementFontSizeNormal}">
    <ldd:LanguageDropdown.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger
            Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference lddTarget}, Path=SelectedItem}"
            TargetType="components:LanguageDropdown"
            Value="null">
            <Setter Property="BorderColor" 
                    Value="{StaticResource PlaceholderAlert}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </ldd:LanguageDropdown.Triggers>
</ldd:LanguageDropdown>

and also I tried another way. At the top of the ContentView I added a resource like
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <bhl:IsLanguageNullOrEmptyConverter x:Key="IsLanguageNullOrEmpty" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

and then I use this in the trigger
<ldd:LanguageDropdown
    x:Name="lddTarget"
    Placeholder="{lang:Translate DictionaryLanguage}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding LanguageTarget}"
    SemanticProperties.Description="{lang:Translate DictionaryLanguage}"
    TextSize="{StaticResource ElementFontSizeNormal}">
    <ldd:LanguageDropdown.Triggers>
        <MultiTrigger TargetType="components:LanguageDropdown">
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding LanguageTarget, 
                    Converter={StaticResource IsLanguageNullOrEmpty}}" 
                Value="True" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="#FF0000" />
        </MultiTrigger>
    </ldd:LanguageDropdown.Triggers>
</ldd:LanguageDropdown>

Every time I try to add the behaviour, I get the error

Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I created a simple demo, and the demo is working with this code.

You can move x:Name="emptyLanguageItem" to ldd:LanguageDropdown,instead of placing it in bhl:IsLanguageNullOrEmptyConverter.For more information,you can refer to trigger.

Your defined a behavior by the name of IsLanguageNullOrEmptyBehavior but then used a converter <bhl:IsLanguageNullOrEmptyConverter x:Name="emptyLanguageItem" /> am i tripping or something?

@FreakyAli I'm not sure I understand.

The name of your behavior does not match in xaml and C# files you have added here is it a typo or a mistake?

Oh the name you mean. Sorry, you are right. Changed now

Can you show the code about LanguageDropdown？
